# Django Form inputs show up as blank in Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-admin

I'm creating software for an ice cream company, and I'd like to get the customer's information from the order entry HTML. But when I fill out the first name, last name, shipping address, etc, it shows up in Django admin as blank. Here's my code:

***forms.py***

```
from django import forms
from orderentry.models import customerInfo, orderInfo

class customerForm(forms.ModelForm):

    firstName = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    lastName = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    shippingAddress = forms.CharField(max_length=60)
    billingAddress = forms.CharField(max_length=60)

    class Meta:
        model = customerInfo
        fields = ('firstName','lastName','shippingAddress', 'billingAddress',)
```

***views.py***

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
import orderentry
from orderentry.forms import customerForm

def getCustomerInfo(request):
    form = customerForm(request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            orderentry.forms.firstName = form.cleaned_data['firstName']
            orderentry.forms.lastName = form.cleaned_data['lastName']
            orderentry.forms.shippingAddress = form.cleaned_data['shippingAddress']
            orderentry.forms.billingAddress = form.cleaned_data['billingAddress']
            return redirect('/orderentry')

    else:
        form=customerForm()
    
    return render(request, 'orderentry.html', {'form' : form})
```

***orderentry.html***

```
<p>
         <!--Basic Customer Information--> 

        <form method = "post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <button type = "submit">Place your order!</button> 
        </form>

</p>
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from inventory.models import item, sizeCounts
import uuid

class customerInfo (models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Customer Information"
        verbose_name_plural = "Customer Information"

    customer_first_name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=30)
    customer_last_name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=30)
    shipping_address = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    billing_address = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    customer_status_choices = [('PREFERRED', 'preferred'), ('OKAY', 'okay'), ('SHAKY', 'shaky')]
    customer_status = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices = customer_status_choices, default="PREFERRED")

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.customer_first_name, self.customer_last_name)
```

**Here's what it looks like in Admin**

[image]

It is blank in the python shell as well.

I'm new to Django. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you share the model and ModelAdmin?

Comment: Did you override `__str__()` on your model?

Comment: I did override __str__(). When I create objects through Django admin, they show up just fine. I updated my original post with the model as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't comment yet so I will post my thoughts here. I think the error may be in your form with your fields variable. I think that the form field names need to match the model's attribute names, otherwise it won't pair together the value from the form with the model attribute. I could be wrong, but that is what I think. So maybe try to match up your form field names with the names of the fields in your model.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. If it worked don't forget to accept my answer please.